# Laravel Kernel.php is called by cron - is it run for every http GET also?

Tags: laravel

Code in my \App\Console\Kernel.php is getting a little complicated. I am worried that it might be executed every time a person hits a http endpoint, or every time an API call is made to my Laravel app.

Is the *only* purpose of Kernel.php to set up the schedule for the scheduled tasks? Therefore is it only called when cron calls the

```
artisan schedule:run
```

?

I ask because I am now looping over all of my clients, looking up a preference for what timezone, time and day of week they want to receive a report, and calling

```
$schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\EmailReport)->weeklyOn($dayOfWeekInt,$timeHm)->timezone($timezone);;
```

This involves many db queries, and I don't want it to run every time I make an API query, or request a page from my browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the console kernel is only called for console commands, and the HTTP kernel is only called when a request is made to the app. You could test this by adding a `sleep(100)` call in your console kernel and then making a HTTP request to your app.

Comment: Thanks for answering within 15 minutes! I had this question on the laravel.com forum for a week with zero answers. Good to have an answer from UTC+10 time zone.